# DataTemplate created using XamlReader fails to find StaticResources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

This code fails to load properly, while declaring the same DataTemplate in XAML works fine.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Resources.Add("a", "Hello");
    DataTemplate t = GetObject("<DataTemplate><Label Content=\"{Binding Source={StaticResource a}}\"/></DataTemplate>") as DataTemplate;
    list.ItemTemplate = t;
    list.Items.Add(77);
}

public static Object GetObject(string xaml)
{
    MemoryStream sr = null;
    ParserContext pc = new ParserContext();
    sr = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xaml));
    pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");
    pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    return XamlReader.Load(sr, pc);
}
```

I need to do this in code. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem: Instead of using StaticResource, I defined the resource as a property and using RelativeSource.AncestorType found the window, then using Path accessed the property.

Answer (score 4):

I think a `StaticResource` needs to be resolved at load time and since it isn't in the context, it'll fail. A `DynamicResource` would have worked since it can wait until queried to provide the value but a `DynamicResource` can't be used as the Source for a `Binding`.

If your situation allows it, you can add the resource to the `DataTemplate` instead like this

```
DataTemplate t = GetObject(@"
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Resources>
            <sys:String x:Key=""a"">Hello</sys:String>
        </DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Label Content=""{Binding Source={StaticResource a}}""/>
    </DataTemplate>") as DataTemplate;
list.ItemTemplate = t;
```

You would also need to add the Xmlns Dictionary

```
pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("sys", "clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib");
```

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the suggestion, but this is not possible in my scenario. The resource is a List and is shared among many datatemplates (for many different columns generated at runtime)